# Simplifying CASE Statement with Correlated Subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I simplify the below `CASE` statement, which runs the same correlated subquery twice?

```
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT val1
            FROM t1
                WHERE out.id = t1.t1
                    AND condition) IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE (SELECT val1
            FROM t1
                WHERE out.id = t1.t1
                    AND condition)
END     AS desired_value
```

In the above code, `out` is the table being referenced outside the subquery, and the `SELECT` statement is guaranteed to always give one value or `NULL`.

Ideally, I would like to have this subquery run only once.

Comment: From what you posted I don't think you need a subquery here at all. But this is only a code snippet and hard to tell without some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `coalesce()` doesn't actually fix the problem (because SQL Server runs the first argument twice when the value is `null`). . . the correlated query is still run twice.  `isnull()` does fix that problem:

```
isnull( (SELECT val1
         FROM t1
         WHERE out.id = t1.t1 AND condition
        ) , 0
     ) AS desired_value
```

Or, you can use an aggregation query:

```
(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(val1), 0)
 FROM t1
 WHERE out.id = t1.t1 AND condition
) AS desired_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have your "out" table in FROM clause of a query, so try to get rid of the sub-query completely:

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.val1, 0) as desired_value
FROM out
LEFT JOIN t1 on out.id = t1.t1 AND condition
```